# Serverless AutoScaling DynamoDB Error : ScalingTargetId must be in the format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am increasing read capacity using auto scaling. I am getting error

> An error occurred: DynamoDBReadScalingPolicy - ScalingTargetId must be
>   in the format: "ResourceId|ScalableDimension|ServiceNamespace

Here is my code

```
DynamoDBAutoscalingRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com
        Path: /
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: DynamoDBAutoscaling
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: 2012-10-17
              Statement:
                - Action:
                    - "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
                    - "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
                    - "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm"
                    - "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
                    - "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms"
                  Effect: "Allow"
                  Resource: "*"    
    DynamoDBReadScalableTarget:
      Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
      Properties:
        ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits
        MinCapacity: 5
        MaxCapacity: 25
        ResourceId: Fn::Ref::[TestTableDynamoDbTable]
        RoleARN: Fn::GetAtt::[DynamoDBAutoscalingRole, Arn]
        ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
    DynamoDBReadScalingPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
      Properties:
        PolicyName: Read Scaling Policy
        PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
        ScalingTargetId: Fn::Ref::[DynamoDBReadScalableTarget]
        TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
          PredefinedMetricSpecification:
            PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization
          ScaleOutCooldown: 60
          ScaleInCooldown: 60
          TargetValue: 30.0
```

Comment: Instead of `ScalingTargetId: Fn::Ref::[DynamoDBReadScalableTarget]` try `!Ref DynamoDBReadScalableTarget`

Comment: I have tried but is not allowing me to write **!Ref** Syntax. **Error :**  unknown tag !<!Ref>

Comment: You could give this plugin a go. It does just that and simplifies the syntax. https://github.com/ACloudGuru/serverless-plugin-dynamo-autoscaling

Comment: guessing no one found an answer to this?